# Backbone form, escape

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have developped a very simple Backbone app on one page of my website and having issues with forms.

I have a list (collection of items) and when I click on the name of an item, it is replaced by a form.

When i edit the name and press enter it works fine, but I don't find the solution to:
- escape the form if I press "esc" key or better, anywhere else on the page
- save my item when i press enter, when I did not modify the text.

Right now, when I click on an item and load the form, I am forced to change the name and press enter if I want to exit the for.

Here is my edit form Backbone view:

```
var EditForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Item,
    template: _.template('<form>' +
        '<input name=name value="<%= name %>" />' +
        '</form>'),
    events: {
        submit: 'save'
    },
    save: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var newName = this.$('input[name=name]').val();
        this.model.set({name: newName}); 
        this.model.save();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});
```

If anyone already implemented that I would be very thankful to have an example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a "keyup" handler on your view and check the keycode in its handler. Something like the following :

```
//modify your events object like this
events:{
   submit: "save",
   "keyup": "checkAndHandleCancel"
}

//handler
checkAndHandleCancel: function(e){
 if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
  //handle your cancel action here
 } 
}
```

Please keep in mind that this would only work if the focus is on the form. If you need to handle a global "cancel", you'd need to have a similar "keyup" handler on the document and then propagate that event to your view.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I had tried some stuff like this but would not work. Your example is working perfectly.